# Intervals using Standard Error vs Intervals using RMSE

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, standard-deviation, standard-error, prediction-interval

I understand that in creating prediction intervals for point prediction we typically use *root mean-squared error* (RMSE) if we meet our linearity, homoskedacity, and normality conditions. Our normality and homoskedacity conditions allow us to use the empirical rules to construct intervals. That is about $95\%$ of our data at say $x = x_0$ is within two RMSE of our prediction.

However, in creating confidence intervals we use standard error(sample standard deviation divided by n-1). I understand that we typically do this in parameter estimation. For example, when predicting the $\beta 's$ in linear regression, we might make a confidence interval for specific betas. Here we're essentially admitting that we don't actually know the true standard deviation, but we have a **sampled** population form which we'll estimate the standard deviation. This estimate is called the standard error. We can use this approximation even if we don't have the conditions I stated above, **correct?**

My question I guess is if we are already admitting to not knowing the standard deviation because we don't have the entire population's dataset, shouldn't we also use standard error in our prediction intervals as well? It also has the benefit of not needing to meet any conditions unlike in our RMSE interval.